# How do "beyond the rails" analog switches work?

Tags: power-supply, switches, analog, multiplexer, cmos

I'm familiar with using CMOS switches ("[transmission gates](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4243)") for [switching analog signals](http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/cd4053/cd4053.htm), but you can't use them for switching voltages beyond their supply rails.  (So if you have a single supply circuit, and a voltage signal that's been AC-coupled and to a ground reference, you cannot use a CMOS switch because the voltage of the signal drops below ground, which is the negative supply for the switch.)

However, there are [some analog switches](http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/switches/beyond-the-rails.cfm) that will switch ±25 V signals with a power supply of 0 V and +3.3 V.  How do they work?  Is it simple to build a circuit like this out of discrete parts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do they work?

They have integrated charge pumps to create internal supply voltages that are greater than ±25 V.

> Is it simple to build a circuit like this out of discrete parts?

Possible? Yes. Simple? Not particularly.

Comment: Would it be worth mentioning that the elevated supply rails don't need to source or sink any significant amount of current and, as a consequence, the charge pumps can be very small?

Comment: Making the circuit out of discrete parts gets complicated, but a charge pump can be two diodes, two caps, and a square wave from a microcontroller.  Integrated standalone charge pumps are also available, if the beyond-the-rails parts don't meet OP's specification.

Comment: Wouldn't this produce at least small amounts of switching noise?

Comment: All charge pumps make switching noise.  If you roll your own you can set the frequency or filter it or postregulate it.  Certainly switching noise is a design consideration.

Comment: Some, not all, of those chips seem very explicit on the charge pump properties and what start-up and noise considerations are involved.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Doh.  Now that I look for it, I see it.  "...contain a total of three charge pumps to generate bias voltages for the internal switches"  I had skimmed them looking for an equivalent circuit diagram with some special arrangement of transmission gates, but of course there wasn't one.

Answer (score 0):

markrages wrote:
"Making the circuit out of discrete parts gets complicated, but a charge pump can be two diodes, two caps, and a square wave from a microcontroller."

And a potentiometer if you want a variable-voltage charge pump. It acts as a voltage divider, it's placed across the pump diode and just upstream of the pump capacitor. If you want the charge pump to quick charge just as it's starting up, put a momentary switch between the output of the pump diode and the input of the storage diode.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YFp7.png

[image]

Comment: Beware, the question is from 2014, so you might not get traction from the OP.